# create animated appearing slide css/jquery from payday2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Dear Stackoverflow members. Im looking for something simular to payday 2`s assault introduction. where there is nothing first, but then animating in, and ends up like this:

[image]

I also have a youtube video that are showing how its appearing: https://youtu.be/RgGwj0ULslg?t=5m36s

**Q: How can i make this kind of appearing bar?

i tried for myself, but all i could do is something like this, and nothing else ( no fadein like payday2, etc)
:
[image]

```
        <div id="assault" class="colorback" style="height:70px; width:185px; background-color:yellow; opacity: 0.9;border: 1px solid #cccc00;position:relative;">
                <p class="marquee">
                    Police Assault in progress</p>
                <div id="texter" class="" style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold;bottom: 0;position: absolute;font-size: 11px;padding-bottom: 2px;padding-left: 4px;">Assault against <a href="/journey">Journey</a></div>
            </div>


 @keyframes marquee {
                    0%   { text-indent: 14.5em }
                    100% { text-indent: -14.5em }
                }
                .marquee {
                    overflow:hidden;
                    width: 180px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    padding-top: 18px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    color:#a75144;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    animation: marquee 7s linear infinite;
                }

                .colorback {
                    background-image: url('http://caviar.dtmcdn.com/static/images/box/white.png');
                    background-repeat: repeat-x;
                }



   .assault {
                    height:70px;
                    width:185px;
                    background-color:yellow;
                    opacity: 0.4;
                    border: 1px solid #cccc00;
                    position:relative;
                }
```

Comment: Did you try to do something or just hope someone will do it instead

Comment: What have you tried anything? best answer for this is to use `jquery.animate()`

Comment: @Nameismy updated the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I see this making the simplest way is trough **CSS Animations**. The main component of CSS animations are `@keyframes` you should look it up.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-introduction-to-css-animation--cms-21068

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: if you look at my code that the only thing i were able to do. could you help me some more on the appearing animation from the youtube clip?

Comment: Your first question lacked every information, you havent showed any code whatsoever, there were also other people asking you if you actually did anything before asking and this was my response to you. This site isn't: "can you please show an example of this", no! Pick a speciffic question and ask. I believe if you go in css animations at the end of the day/week/ you will be able todo this...